# Retrieving added jquery rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem retrieving all the data inside the rows added by the user. I tried using my variable `reclist` to retrieve the records but it give me blanks.

The source code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btnAdd').live('click',function(){
      var name = $('#txtName').val();
      var name2 = $('#txtName2').val();
      $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + name2 + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
  });

   $('#tbNames td img.delete').live('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
   });
 });
</script>

<input id="txtName" type="text" />
<input id="txtName2" type="text" />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
   <table id="tbNames" >
      <tr>
         <td><b>Name</b></td>
         <td><b>Name2</b></td>
         <td><b>Delete</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bingo</td>
          <td>Tingo</td>
          <td><img src="Delete.gif" height="15" class="delete" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_app").button();
    $("#submit_app").click(function() {
    var reclist = $("#txtName").val();
    console.log(reclist);
    });
});
</script>

<input id="submit_app" type="button" style="height: 35px; width: 225px" value="Add New User" />
```

Please advise if I have miss any coding.

Comment: do you getting any kind of error in firebug??

Comment: Comment this line `$("#submit_app").button();` and try

Comment: You can use `th` for headers, instead of `td` with `<b>`.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure actually the `$("#submit_app").button();` is linked by some code above. I tried using `var reclist = $("#txtName").text();` and it display the following in the console: `NameName2DeleteBingoTingo`. Anyway to split them properly as I only need a list of info like `Bingo` and `Tingo`?

Comment: You can do that easily in my code. Create two arrays, and inside click handler add items to them. You can use the `skipLastColumn` counter for this. Let me know if you require any help in that. Also check the jsfiddle.net link, there you can test and modify your code also.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure, yep. I saw your code after I finish enter my comment. Thanks and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VuxJT/2/) demo on jsFiddle.net. This will give you all the values inside `td` of your table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnAdd').live('click', function() {
    var name = $('#txtName').val();
    var name2 = $('#txtName2').val();
    $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + name2 + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
  });

  $('#tbNames td img.delete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });

  //$("#submit_app").button(); //Commented this line
  $("#submit_app").click(function() {
      var skipFirstRow = 0; //Skip first row
      $("#tbNames tr").each(function() {
          if (skipFirstRow++ == 0) return;
          var skipLastColumn = 0;
          $(this).children("td").each(function() {
              if (skipLastColumn++ == 2) return;
              alert($(this).html());
          });
     });
     var reclist = $("#txtName").val();
     console.log(reclist);
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VuxJT/3/) fiddle. In this you will get the values in two arrays.

Comment: Check the updated jsFiddle. It will give you array. Check console.

Comment: I find that I need to have rep of 15 in order to vote here. Never mind, once I reach rep 15, I vote.

Comment: You have reached there. Has given +1 to your question :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124311/adding-array-data-to-jquery-table ??? :)

Answer (score 0):

$("#txtName") refers to the text box you declared in

```
<input id="txtName" type="text" />
```

Since you want to retrieve all the data that you have inserted into the table, you should be using $("td", "#tbNames") and retrieving their .text()

```
$("td", "#tbNames").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Your advise do work but there is always a extra row being log. Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind click event as live. Since normal bind will only bind events to element found on page rendering first time

Here is corrected part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_app").button();
    $("#submit_app").live('click', function() {
     var reclist = $("#txtName").val();
      console.log(reclist);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're submit button was't getting triggered

http://jsfiddle.net/gBHh2/