# Adding array data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem adding the data array into my table. There is no error message shown in the firebug and the data was not added into the table as rows using the `$("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[0] + "</td><td>" + data[2] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");`.

**The Logic (Javascript)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [];
data.push("Coco", "Mandy");
data.push("Suzze", "Candy");
data.push("Janny", "Jacky");


$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#btnAdd').live('click', function() {
        var name = $('#txtName').val();
        var name2 = $('#txtName2').val();
        $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + name2 + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
     });

     $('#tbNames td img.delete').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
     });

     $("#insert_data").click(function() {
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[0] + "</td><td>" + data[2] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
        }
     });      
});
</script>
```

**The HTML form**

```
<input id="txtName" type="text" />
<input id="txtName2" type="text" />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
<table id="tbNames" border="1" >
     <tr>
         <th>Name</b></th>
         <th>Name2</b></th>
         <th>Delete</b></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Bingo</td>
         <td>Tingo</td>
         <td><img src="Delete.gif" height="15" class="delete" /></td>
      </tr>
</table>
<input id="insert_data" type="button" style="height: 35px; width: 225px" value="Retrieve Default User" />
```

Please advise if I miss out anything. Thanks.

## **The Solution**

(Will be insert into the solution text area tomorrow since I got this message `Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.`

**Bug 1**

Changing the

```
data.push("Coco", "Mandy"); 
data.push("Suzze", "Candy"); 
data.push("Janny", "Jacky");
```

to

```
data.push(["Coco", "Mandy"]); 
data.push(["Suzze", "Candy"]); 
data.push(["Janny", "Jacky"]);
```

**Bug 2**

Changing the

```
$("#insert_data").click(function() { 
   for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){ 
        $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[0] + "</td><td>" + data[2] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>"); 
    } 
});
```

to

```
$("#insert_data").click(function() { 
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){ 
        $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[i][0] + "</td><td>" + data[i][1] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Now you are doing the reverse :)

Comment: @AmarPalsapure yep and a chance for you to increase your rep points too. :D

Comment: Is this homework you are doing? or some project?

Comment: It is neither homework nor project. Just trying out how I can play around with the `table` and if I can extend the functionality of the `table`

Comment: @AmarPalsapure I found the solution. There are 2 bugs in my code.

Comment: I will post the solution here as answer.

Comment: **Bug 1**

Changing the 

    `data.push("Coco", "Mandy");
    data.push("Suzze", "Candy");
    data.push("Janny", "Jacky");`


to 

    `data.push(["Coco", "Mandy"]);
    data.push(["Suzze", "Candy"]);
    data.push(["Janny", "Jacky"]);`

Comment: **Bug 2**

Changing the 

      `$("#insert_data").click(function() {
          for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[0] + "</td><td>" + data[2] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
          }
      });`



to

      `$("#insert_data").click(function() {
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[i][0] + "</td><td>" + data[i][1] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
      }
      });`

Comment: Cannot post my solution here yet cause - `Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.`

Comment: Check my solution. It handles your case :)

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Yep. I notice the two bug and have change the coding. I was wondering how can I play the html `table` to even higher level. Any suggestion? (probably creating a game using the `html table` ??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data arrary contains: ['Coco','Mandy','Suzze','Candy','Janny','Jacky']

So, currently your code produces:

```
<tr><td>Coco</td><td>Suzze</td><td><img ...etc></td></tr>
<tr><td>Coco</td><td>Suzze</td><td><img ...etc></td></tr>
<tr><td>Coco</td><td>Suzze</td><td><img  ...etc
```

Did you mean to write:

```
$("#insert_data").click(function() {
  for(var i=0; i<data.length-1; i=i+2){
    $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td><td>" + data[i+1] + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually I notice that there is 2 bugs in my code. Now is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution. Spot the difference :).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = [];
data.push("Coco", "Mandy");
data.push("Suzze", "Candy");
data.push("Janny", "Jacky");


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').live('click', function() {
        var name = $('#txtName').val();
        var name2 = $('#txtName2').val();
        $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + name2 + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
    });

    $('#tbNames td img.delete').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

    $("#insert_data").click(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#tbNames tr:last").after("<tr><td>" + data[i++] 
                 + "</td><td>" + data[i] 
                 + "</td><td><img src='delete.gif' class='delete' height='15' /></td></tr>");
        }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually I notice that there is 2 bugs in my code. Now is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that, but missed answer by 3 mins :(

Comment: it's ok, I am still thinking what to do next to the `table`. probably you can give me some ideas.